# how do i hide elements without using the visibility function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write a code that gives the user more options whenever a button is clicked. 
for example say i have a page with two buttons, one "search for books" and another "search for events". If a user clicks on "search for books" button, on the same page right beneath the search button i want different options to appear. I tried using the css visibility:hidden function and switching it back to visibility:visible using a javascript function. It did work but a huge space from the screen was reserved for the hidden elements. The main window buttons were far apart from each other. on one side there was the "search for books" button and far from it there was the "search for events" button.

Here is part of the code

```
</head>
<div class ="buttons">
<div id="visible">
    <input type="button"  value="Click To Search Faculty Members" onclick="swapform()" class="button">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "form" id="theform" style="visibility: hidden">
    <form name = "type"  value="fm" action="http://localhost:8080/278Project/search.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return goto();">
    <table>
    <span style="box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white inset;">
    <select name="type" >
            <option value="fm"> Faculty Members Search </option>
            </select>
            <tr><td><label class ="textClick">List all Faculty Members<input type="radio" name="select" value=1 ></label>
            <div>                       
            <label class="textClick"> List By Id<input type="radio" name="select" value=2 > </label> 
            <input class="text" type="text" size = "8" placeholder="Insert Id" name="listById" > </div>
            <div>
            <label class="textClick">List By First Name <input type="radio" name="select" value=3 ></label>
            <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Insert Name" name="list" >
            </div>
            <div>
            <label class="textClick">List By Last Name<input type="radio" name="select" value=4 ></label>
            <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Insert Last Name" name="lname" >
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <input type="button" value="Hide" onclick="swapform2()" class="button"> !-->
    <input type="submit" value="Get Info">
    </table>
    </div>
</span>
</form>


<!-- Book Search !-->
<div class="buttons">
<div  id="bvisible">
    <input class ="button" type="button" value="Click To Search Books" onclick="swapbooks()" class="button">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thebookform" style="visibility: hidden">
    <form name = "type" value="ch" action="http://localhost:8080/278Project/search.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return goto();">
    <table>
    <select name="type">
            <option value="ch"> Search for Books</option>
            </select>
            <tr><td><label class ="textClick">List all available Books<input type="radio" name="select" value=1 ></label>
            <div>                       
            <label class="textClick"> List By Id<input type="radio" name="select" value=2 > </label> 
            <input class="text" type="text" size = "8" placeholder="Insert Id" name="listById" > </div>
            <div>
            <label class="textClick">List By Publishers name <input type="radio" name="select" value=3 ></label>
            <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Insert Name" name="list" >
            </div>
            <div>
            <label class="textClick">List Books by year<input type="radio" name="select" value=4 ></label>
            <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Insert Last Name" name="lname" >
            </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Info">
    </table>
```

Comment: @DSG Well now you have! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
display : none
```

This does the same thing, except the empty space the element takes up.

---

And looking at the tags, you have jQuery there. You can use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead.

Comment: Thanks i guess this cleared things up for me

Comment: I still have a question how can i make the elements displayed again
this was my function.. i used inline, but it didn't work
function swapform() {
  var visable
  var hidden
  visable = document.getElementById("visible").innerHTML;
  hidden = document.getElementById("theform").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("visible").innerHTML = inline;
  }

Comment: @user3117253.. You need to set the `style.display` property for the element `document.getElementById("visible").style.display = 'inline';`